# How to verify the signature of a response using a public key with RSAwithSHA256 in C#?

Tags: c#, authentication, cryptography, rsa, sha256

I have a problem verifying a signature using the RSAwithSHA256 procedure in C#. The problem is that the VerifyHash function will always return false, although I believe I'm using the correct procedure. I know RSACryptoServiceProvider is using SHA1 by default for signing, but here I only want to verify the signature. What could have gone wrong?

```
    #region // public //
    public bool Verify(SMBillsAuthResponse response) {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = retrieveCryptoServiceProvider();
        string verificationMessage = getVerificationMessage(response);
        byte[] hash = getSha256Hash(verificationMessage);
        byte[] signature = HexStringToByteArray(response.auth.signature);
        return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature);
    }
    #endregion

    #region // auxiliary //
    private RSACryptoServiceProvider retrieveCryptoServiceProvider() {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(this.publicKeyFile);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        return csp;
    }

    private string getVerificationMessage(SMBillsAuthResponse response) {
        return this.apiKey + response.auth.nonce + response.auth.timestamp + response.transactionId;
    }

    private byte[] getSha256Hash(string message) {
        SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
        return hash;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only problem I had was wrong encoding of the data. Instead of Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message) I used Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message) and it worked.